# MySQL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not updating

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, sql-update

I've got a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Hosts` (
`id` int(128) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`IP` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Port` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Password` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Username` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Tid` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`EquipType` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Version` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
`Status` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Location` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Lastconnection` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`Lastbackup` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
`Backupstatus` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Backupmsg` text,
`Backupfile` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `IP` (`IP`),
KEY `Tid` (`Tid`),
KEY `EquipType` (`EquipType`),
KEY `Status` (`Status`),
KEY `Lastbackup` (`Lastbackup`),
KEY `Backupstatus` (`Backupstatus`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=716 ;
```

In my mind, this means that any time a row is updated, the field 'Lastconnection' should be stamped with the current timestamp.  However, when I run something like:

```
update Hosts set Backupstatus = 'FAIL',  Backupmsg = 'Connection timed out' where Tid = 'SITE001'
```

Lastconnection stays '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.  There's either a database issue I'm not seeing, or I'm completely misunderstanding the 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' clause.

Comment: What is your version?  I only ask because of this bug report: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28904

Comment: That the ts column as you report is filled with '0000-00-00 00:00:00' does contradict my guess it could have smth. to do with the NO_ZERO_DATE mode, but take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date

Comment: I think that may be it.  Many rows are being stamped properly, but some may have duplicate values.  I'll try an upgrade.

Comment: Using null for the datetime column in the query worked for me.

Comment: according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html the current timestamp will update ONLY if one of the values in the row changes (i.e. if all the values stay the same, the `lastconnection` column will not update either even if you run `UPDATE` query)

Answer (score 35):

Have you tried to use null for that field when updating?

You could also try setting default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, rather than `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Nevertheless, whenever I want to have creation and update time I always use the following:

```
...
CREATED timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
UPDATED timestamp NOT NULL default now() on update now(),
....
```

I use `now()`, because is an alias for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and it is shorter. At the end, table structure gets `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so don't worry.

The trick with `CREATED` field is to remember to use null on both fields for `INSERT` statements, for `UPDATE` statements it is not required:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (field1, field2, created, updated)
VALUES ('foo', 'bar', null, null);
```

Comment: More explanation on this... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

Comment: I had to set the timestamp field to `null` in the update statement. Now every time the field is updated (even when the data has not really changed).

Comment: Yes, and there exists other synonyms for NOW() like LOCALTIME, LOCALTIME(), LOCALTIMESTAMP, LOCALTIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Isn't it better to use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` to avoid problems with the MySQL server timezone being different to your application?

Answer (score 20):

It might be the case that the update statement doesn't change anything. If the row with `Tid = 'SITE001'` already has `Backupstatus` set to `'FAIL'` and `Backupmsg` set to `'Connection timed out'` (maybe, set by some previous backup attempt), then MySQL will skip this row and therefore won't change the `Lastconnection` timestamp.

Also, I see `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` more like an administrative feature to keep track of data changes. As a programmer, I would add the timestamp update explicitly:

`update Hosts

set Backupstatus = 'FAIL', Backupmsg = 'Connection timed out', Lastconnection = NOW()
where Tid = 'SITE001'`.

Comment: It's a common mistake true, "on update" clause is more administrative and should not be used like this. If there is no real changements on the data, it will not work.

Answer (score 10):

You must remember that if no value was **changed** on update it won't set the current time stamp,

You have to set the value in query `NOW()` to set for the current time stamp !!!

`update Hosts set Backupstatus = 'FAIL',Lastconnection = NOW() ,  Backupmsg = 'Connection timed out' where Tid = 'SITE001'`

Remember the value must change in order for the current time stamp to change.

Answer (score 1):

To specify automatic properties, use the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` clauses. The order of the clauses does not matter. If both are present in a column definition, either can occur first. Any of the synonyms for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` have the same meaning as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. These are `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, `NOW()`, `LOCALTIME`, `LOCALTIME()`, `LOCALTIMESTAMP`, and `LOCALTIMESTAMP()`.

Use of `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is specific to `TIMESTAMP`. The `DEFAULT` clause also can be used to specify a constant (nonautomatic) default value; for example, `DEFAULT 0` or `DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00'`.

`DEFAULT 0` do not work if the `NO_ZERO_DATE` SQL mode is enabled because that mode causes “zero” date values (specified, for example, as 0 '0000-00-00 00:00:00') to be rejected. Be aware that the `TRADITIONAL` SQL mode includes `NO_ZERO_DATE`.

In addition, you can initialize or update any `TIMESTAMP` column to the current date and time by assigning it a `NULL` value, unless it has been defined with the `NULL` attribute to permit `NULL` values.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is this answer saying to do what the OP was already _doing_, which failed anyway? He said that the timestamp field with `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` **does not change on update**, didn’t he?

Good general information about timestamps; bad answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the record to automatically update the timestamp whenever the record is changed, here's the four simple steps you need to accomplish (could be all in one step, depending on if you're using command line or GUI to administer):

1. Create field to hold auto-updated timestamp (I typically call mine 'modified').
2. Specify field Type as 'TIMESTAMP'
3. Specify field Default as 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
4. Specify field Extra as 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'

Now the field that contains your timestamp will always be updated to the current timestamp anytime the record is updated.

Comment: This just restates information already provided in other answers.

Comment: Concise, easy to read....it helped me! I was only getting an update when it was inserted not updated. I had missed step 4.