# How to update date,year and month to an existing table in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to update the Current date ,month,year to an existing table,and when ever the data in the  table is modified automatically date should be modified .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is addressed in the MySQL documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Also view these questions:

[MySQL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571323/mysql-on-update-current-timestamp-not-updating)

[MySQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on create and on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897002/mysql-current-timestamp-on-create-and-on-update)