# on duplicate key update ... time stamp not updating

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a mySQL statement which ends in:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ....
```

And then I go and update all my values in my row. My issue is in my table when I created it I have a date column with data type:

```
TIMESTAMP
```

And default entry is:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

My issue is that I need the timestamp to update too. Is there a way to have mySQL auto update the time stamp when I update everything else manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL ON UPDATE CURRENT\_TIMESTAMP not updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571323/mysql-on-update-current-timestamp-not-updating)

Comment: If you say - 'I go and update ALL my values in my row', what do you expect from MySQL? MySQL will store ALL row values from UPDATE statement.

Comment: Well I update ever column except fhe time stamp one. Which is similar to when I insert I insert into every column except the fime stamp and mySQL updates the time stamp automatically.

Comment: Can you show CREATE TABLE, UPDATE queries?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for attributes in your table.

Comment: And I don't have to set a value for it?

Comment: So I was just playing around in mySQL work bench. Where do I set the attributes?

Comment: Go to the database and select your table - > then click the structure view->click edit option for the particular filed->now you can see "Attributes" click this dropdown list and choose "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"